# How do i get relationships between users?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called users, that looks like this for example:

Table: users

```
username id 
Simon     6
Ida       7
```

And a relationships table

```
Table: Relationships

me partner
 6       7
```

Now for every relationship that is created the me and partner columns will get the id depending on which one of the users sent the request.

If Ida sends a request to Simon, the column looks like this: me: 7 partner: 6
because Ida is id number 7 and Simon is number 6.

But if Simon sends a request then the columns looks like this: me: 6 partner: 7

What i want to do is to write a query that will get the  right id from the relationships table for every user with a relationship, and then use the id to Join the users table and get the partners username and print it out.

My problem is that the columns Me and Partner can have different values depending on which of the 2 users sended the request first.

How do i write a query that prints out the right information for each and every user and give them the right id of their partner?

How the output should look like:

- From simons point of view*
  : You are in a relationship with Ida.
- From Idas point of view *
  : You are in a relationship with Simon.

Comment: Maybe terms like 'initiator/sender','reciprocator/recipient' would be more appropriate?

Comment: Can you please supply some sample data and expected output? I think that I know what you're trying to do, but it would be easier and faster to not have to guess. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So here you ask a question.. people work to resolve your issue and you not even give a comment on any answer.. left alone accepting...

Comment: I solved the issue by using UNION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to offer an alternative.

Join the user table to the relationship table either on the `me` column or the `partner` column.

Then join the user table back onto the relationship table using the same criteria.

```
SELECT u.username, 
FROM users u
JOIN relationships r ON u.id = r.me OR u.id = r.partner
JOIN users u2 ON r.me = u2.id OR r.partner = u2.id
WHERE u.id = 'THE USER YOU CARE ABOUT'
```

Untested. If you throw up some `CREATE TABLE`s and `INSERT INTO`s we can all have a play.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all users which have a relationship with some user (ex.: id:2) you specify, I would use something like this:

```
SELECT id, username
FROM user, 
    (SELECT receiver_id as rel_id FROM relationship WHERE sender_id=2 union
     SELECT sender_id as rel_id FROM relationship WHERE receiver_id=2) tab
WHERE id=rel_id
```

The inner statement means you are selecting all the relationships in which 2 was the sender and all the relationships in which 2 was the receiver and stacking them in the same column (union).

After that, the table user is used to get the user name from the id.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select username as username, 
    (select username name from users uSubq where uSubq.id = r.partner) as partnername 
    from users u join relationships r on u.id=r.me 
UNION
Select username as username, 
    (select username name from users uSubq where uSubq.id = r.me) as partnername 
    from users u join relationships r on u.id=r.partner;
```

Here is the test for the query:  [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8d5c/1)

If either Ida sent request to Simon or the reverse but not both, use UNION ALL for better performance.